# Unable to Copy XPath to Selenium IDE 2.0.0

Tags: selenium-ide

Whenever I try to Copy Xpath of any item I select through Firebug, I'm just provided with item ID alone.

e.g., `//*[@id="txtUsername"]`

I know that the path would be something lengthy which needs to placed at Target textbox. I tried my level best to get it done but failed with all my attempts :(

Please help me to find out the place where I'm going wrong? Is that either in Firebug or Selenium?????

P.S: I'm using Selenium IDE V2.0.0 and Firebug V1.11.2.

Comment: What do you mean copy xpath? What are you trying to do? If you are trying to locate by the ID you can just type in "id=txtUsername"

Comment: I'm just trying to get the value for 'Target' field in Selenium through Firebug, by copying XPath option it has.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be careful when using Firebug and Selenium together with respect to the XPath.  Firebug will give you the full XPath which is great but Selenium may not understand that target.  You may need to use a much smaller subset of the XPath (e.g. Selenium may want '//input' while Firebug will give you a MUCH larger (the complete) XPath).

for many of the Selenium commands, if you are using the IDE, if you click on part of the page you are automating with the IDE set to Record, you will see a target value display.  To the right of the target value but to the left of the 'Find' box, there should be a drop down menu to give you options for targets.  Depending on the webpage you are automating different targets will work better.

Regardless of which method you choose to use to find the XPath to work with Selenium, I can recommend at least the following:  Use the 'Find' feature I mentioned above.  Place the XPath or any target you want to use in the target value field and click the 'Find' button.  The location will display on the webpage and you will know whether or not you've missed the mark.

I hope this helps!